# Error:The use of xcframeworks is not supported in the legacy build system

Tags: swift, xcode, xcframework

I have created .xcframework and trying to use in another app by embedding the .xcframework in xcode project, but I am getting an error **"error: the use of xcframeworks is not supported in the legacy build system"**. I am testing this in xcode 11.3

Comment: You can try turning off the legacy build system. Go to `File` -> `Workplace Settings` -> `Build System` -> Change to `New Build System (Default)`.

Comment: Project Settings, not workplace setting

Comment: In words its confusing which project settings to select. See a shot video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3_efYinxac

Answer (score 2):

You can try turning off the legacy build system. Go to <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Workplace Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Build System</kbd> -> Change to *New Build System (Default)*.

Comment: I have already new build system, but nothing changes... same error.